# Listen to Scroll and stop Mouse Hover events while scrolling - Flutter

Tags: flutter, animation, scroll, mobile-development

I have a `SingleChildScrollView` with multiple elements inside it. And some of them are `MouseRegion` widgets. That listens to hover and starts some animation.

But that kinda messes up, when it gets hovered while scrolling down/up on the `SingleChildScrollView` widget.
Now I just want to listen to the scroll state. And don't allow to animate while the use is **`scrolling`**.

So far I've tried 2 different ways to do that -

1. Listen to the `ScrollNotification`

   ```dart
    onNotification: (notification) {
        if (notification is ScrollStartNotification) {
          _canPoint = false;
        } else if (notification is ScrollUpdateNotification) {
          _canPoint = false;
        } else if (notification is ScrollEndNotification) {
          _canPoint = true;
        }
        return true;
     },
   ```

   And use the `_canPoint` variable with a `IgnorePointer` Widget.

   ```dart
   IgnorePointer(
      ignoring: !_canPoint,
      child: ...(Section that listens to MouseHover),
   ),
   ```
2. Check the scroll state of the scrollable of current `context`. And not forward with the animation based on that.

   ```dart
   _runAnimation() {
      final notifier = Scrollable.of(context).position.isScrollingNotifier;
      if(notifier.value) return;
      //* Continue with the animation.
   }
   ```

But none of them worked as aspected so far. I was looking for a better way to handle the situation.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add  provider package to pubspec.yaml

define ScrollHoverProvider

```
class ScrollHoverProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  bool _canAnimate = true;

  bool get canAnimate => _canAnimate;

  void startScrolling() {
    _canAnimate = false;
  notifyListeners();
  }

  void stopScrolling() {
    _canAnimate = true;
    notifyListeners();
   }
}
```

Wrap your app with the Provider:

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
     create: (context) => ScrollHoverProvider(),
     child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}



class CustomHover extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   // Access the provider
   final provider = Provider.of<ScrollHoverProvider>(context);

   return MouseRegion(
     onEnter: (event) {
      if (provider.canAnimate) {
       // Trigger hover animation
       }
      },
        child: Container(
        // Your widget code
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That didn't work. It's exactly the same as before.

Comment: try to use provider package 
 final canAnimate = context.watch<ScrollHoverProvider>().canAnimate;
 I will update the code